# Angular2 (RC.6) renderer.setElementClass setting isAdd to false doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have the following directive which after the view is checked it adds a class to the element `checkbox-unselected`. Then when the element is clicked it calls a method which should remove the class `checkbox-unselected` and replace it with another class `checkbox-selected`. While the new class is added as expected the old class isn't removed. I can't find any documentation on this method but from what I have been able to assertion setting the value of the third parameter isAdd to false should tell the method to remove the provided class, but that doesn't happen.

```
export class SharedCustomCheckboxDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
  @Input('cmgSharedCustomCheckbox') isChecked: string;

  constructor(  private element: ElementRef,
                private renderer: Renderer ) { }

  public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement.children[0], 'checkbox-unselected', true);
  }

  @HostListener('click') click(): void {
    if (this.isChecked !== 'true') {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement.children[0], 'checkbox-unselected', false);
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement.children[0], 'checkbox-selected', true);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by me using AfterViewChecked, which is called repeatedly, adding that class back on the element after it was removed. Changing out to AfterViewInit resolved the issue.